# file not sent with xhrhttprequest

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, xmlhttprequest

This is my first time sending a picture with XHR and I can't log it in the network console.
Is it not getting sent or what might be wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ovbpym4c/2/
```

This is the log in the network console.

```
Array
(
    [name] => susu
    [password] => 123
    [cpassword] => 123
    [phone] => 131213141111
    [email] => test@gmail.com
    [displayCountry] => Vietnam
    [age] => 39
    [address] => test
)
```

There is no photo in the array.

Comment: Sorry i got it i tried   $filename=$_FILES['pic']['name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
$filename=$_FILES['pic']['name'];
echo($filename);
```